# Which signal numbers does GDB use?

Tags: gdb, signals

I've been trying to put together a kind of 'remote gdb agent', but I don't seem to find the right signal numbers for stop packets. Where/how can I find the signal numbers gdb actually uses? At least the gdb-multiarch from Debian Jessie repo acts weird.

Signal 31 is shown as SIG37 - real-time event 37 (I expected SIGUSR2)
and if I send signal 10, dgb shows "Can't send signals to this remote system.  SIGURG not sent." and sends a 'c'-packet (I expected SIGBUS).

With remote and serial debugs on, I can see that the signals 31 and 10 are actually received by gdb.

[edit]
By trying I found out the first 30 signals. Here are the first ones:
(the asterisk meand that can't continue with debugging)
2 SIGINT
4 SIGILL
5 SIGTRAP
6 SIGABRT *
7 SIGEMT
8 SIGFPE
9 SIGKILL
10 SIGURG *
11 SIGSTOP
12 SIGTSTP
13 SIGCONT *
14 SIGCHLD *
15 SIGTTIN *
16 SIGTTOU
17 SIGIO *
18 SIGXCPU *

[edit2]

```
[r $][T][1][0][#][b][5]Packet received: T10
  ...
  Can't send signals to this remote system.  SIGURG not sent.
  Sending packet: $c#63...[\x00][\x00][\x00][\x00][\x00][
  r +]Ack
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gdb remote protocol uses its own numbers for signals.  These have to be translated to the correct system values by your remote agent.  See [the documentation](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Stop-Reply-Packets.html) (first paragraph) for details; I think the signal numbers are only available in a gdb header file.

Comment: Any idea where to find the gdb-multiarch 7.7.1 sources for Debian? Or any gdb-multiarch 7.7.1 sources? And how does a remote agent know which gdb client version uses it? I read the Debian local gdb (x86_64) includes, but the signal numbers there were quite different.

Comment: I think the signal numbers should be constant over time.  What makes you think they've changed?  FWIW the file you really want to read is $src/include/gdb/signals.def; this is processed with macros at include time.

Comment: I haven't found the sources anywhere, and this: https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=blob_plain;f=include/gdb/signals.def;hb=HEAD isn't even close.

Comment: I believe that's what gdb's gdbserver implementation uses.

Comment: Well, if I send 'T10' from the remote 'agent', that gdb-multiarch shows that the signal is SIGURG, and automatically sends a 'cont'-command ('c'-packet). I understand that in most systems it's SIGBUS.

Comment: And what the heck is SIGPHONE?

Comment: `T` packet signal numbers are two *hex* digits, so `T10` means "signal 16", which is `SIGURG`.  You want `T0A`.  I have no idea what `SIGPHONE` might be, sometimes these things come from ancient systems that don't exist any more.

Comment: Aargh, how could I miss that! HEX digits. Like everything else. THANKS! Since I don't seem to be able to upvote your comment, I'll upvote your answer.